# how to stop a non-numeric value encountered warning in php

Tags: php

Im trying to understand php a little better so Im making an application that converts different units. In my code I ask the user to enter a value for units of length, volume, and weight, then check a multiple checkboxes to convert what unit they want. I have everything working except for when I enter no input in a input box I get a warning A non-numeric value encountered in " ". So my question is how do I stop this warning from showing and just have it say you forgot to enter an input.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="convert_units2.php" method="POST"> 
    <?php
        //use from other php code
        // require("form_functions.php");
        //
        // include("form_functions.php");
        function generate_options_pulldown($options){
            echo '<select name = "' . $options["title"] . '_unit">';
            foreach($options["list"] as $opt){
                echo '<option value="' . $opt . '">' . $opt . '</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';
        }
        function generate_options_checkbox($options){
            foreach($options["list"] as $opt){
                echo '<lable><input type ="checkbox" name="'. $opt . '">' .$opt .'</label>';
            }
        }
        function generate_conversion_form($units){
            echo '<input type="text" size="10" name="' . $units["title"] . '_val"> ';
            generate_options_pulldown($units);
            echo "-->";
            generate_options_checkbox($units);
        }
        //
        $length_units = array("title"=>"length","list"=>array("meter","mm","cm","km"));
        $volume_units = array("title"=>"volume","list"=>array("liter","oz","gallon"));
        $weight_units = array("title"=>"weight","list"=>array("gram","mg","kg"));

        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET"){
            generate_conversion_form($length_units);
            echo "<p>";
            generate_conversion_form($volume_units);
            echo "<p>";
            generate_conversion_form($weight_units);
            echo '<p><input type="submit" value="Convert"></p>';
        }
        else{//Post
            // var_dump($_POST);
            $length_units_conversion_table = array("meter"=>1,"mm"=>1000,"cm"=>100,"km"=>0.001);
            $from_unit = $_POST["length_unit"];
            $val = $_POST["length_val"];
            $meter = $val / $length_units_conversion_table[$from_unit];
            foreach($length_units_conversion_table as $unit => $rate){
                if(isset($_POST[$unit]) and $_POST[$unit] == 'on' )
                printf("%s %s is %s %s<br>",$val, $from_unit,$meter * $rate, $unit);   
            }
            
            echo '<br>';
            $volumn_units_conversion_table = array("liter"=>1,"oz"=>33.8,"gallon"=>0.264);
            $from_unit = $_POST["volume_unit"];
            $val = $_POST["volume_val"];
            $liter = $val / $volumn_units_conversion_table[$from_unit];
            foreach($volumn_units_conversion_table as $unit => $rate){
                if(isset($_POST[$unit]) and $_POST[$unit] == 'on' )
                printf("%s %s is %s %s<br>",$val, $from_unit,$liter * $rate, $unit);
            }
            echo '<br>';
            $weight_units_conversion_table = array("gram"=>1,"mg"=>1000,"kg"=>0.001);
            $from_unit = $_POST["weight_unit"];
            $val = $_POST["weight_val"];
            $gram = $val / $weight_units_conversion_table[$from_unit];
            foreach($weight_units_conversion_table as $unit => $rate){
                if(isset($_POST[$unit]) and $_POST[$unit] == 'on' )
                printf("%s %s is %s %s<br>",$val, $from_unit,$gram * $rate, $unit);
            }
        }
    ?>
    
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it giving you a line number with the error message?

Comment: Also, please share your debugging attempts

Answer (score 0):

you can check if the value is numeric using the function is_numeric() (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)

```
if(!is_numeric($_POST["volume_val"])) { ...} )
```

For the specific case where no value has been set, you can either check that the value is not an empty string,

```
if( $_POST["volume_val"] == '') {...}
```

or convert an empty string to zero

```
$volume_val = empty($_POST["volume_val"]) ? 0 : $_POST["volume_val"];
```

Answer (score 0):

For the empty field alert, you can use the required attribute in the input, so when you submit the form you'll get the "Field required" warning and the form won't submit.

Then, in the POST part of your code, you can test $_POST["length_unit"] for empty:
if (empty(trim($_POST["length_unit"])))

if this is true then ... you can either treat this as 0 or just send a warning.

You can also test for numeric value before processing:
if (is_numeric($_POST["length_unit"]))